# ConvertFrom-Json output doesn't work for Select-Object

Tags: json, powershell

I am using PowerShell 4 to make a series of web requests.  From one call I get a generic array - for the sake of discussion it looks like this

```
$data = '[{"Id":"1","Name":"One"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Two"}]'
```

I am trying to parse this data to pull out the Name properties.  However, when I use the following call it writes a line with Name and no information under it:

```
$data | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object Name
```

But if I save the object to an intermediate object like this it works:

```
$o1 = $data | ConvertFrom-Json
$o1 | Select-Object Name
```

I get the proper output.

The object types are different but I don't understand why.  Here's output from relevant Get-Member calls:

```
$test | ConvrtFrom-Json | gm

TypeName: System.Object[]
```

and

```
$o1 | gm

TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong in terms of my collection management?  I'd like to be able to do this in one statement.

Comment: `($data | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select-Object Name`

Comment: Argh... ridiculous... it works with the parentheses.  Want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the parentheses are needed for some mysterious reason, as OP pointed out in the comment. Adding parentheses was the fix for me as well.
I am not sure why this breaks without parens, but I can confirm that code without parens is not an issue when executed in powershell core.